# Cancel a running build process in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build-process, abort

Is it possible to cancel/abort a running build process in Visual Studio 2008?
**How?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> should do the trick?

Comment: I was obviously too tired, because I was hitting Esc and/or Ctrl-C like mad. But didn't think of Ctrl-Break, because it's a tricky key combination to press. But thanks. It works.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but with multi-processor C++ builds, canceling with ctrl-break or "alt-b a" doesn't actually seem to kill the build.  I just did a 4 processor compilation and tried to kill it and two of the thread stopped, 2 kept going.

Answer (score 5):

Try hitting Ctrl+Pause(=break) on your keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

While building, the `Build` menu has a `Cancel` menu item... which also shows the key combination in your particular configuration (default is, as answered by [lz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171059/iz), <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

It's not about VS 2008 but is probably the most universal and easy way to stop a build (and VS as all):
[image]